# YouTubePlayerView inside RecyclerView item

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Is it possible to autoplay videos using Youtube API while scrolling RecyclerView?

Comment: I'm looking into the same issue. It appears `YouTubePlayerView` cannot be inflated within a RecyclerView cell. This is the error message I am receiving: **A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Look at this example: https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/my-mini-project/multiple-youtube-video-in-recyclerviewlistview-in-android/

Comment: But this plays video after click and opens new activity, is it possible to play inside viewholder?

Comment: I think you can do that if you use YouTubePlayerFragment instead YouTubePlayerView generating a list of YouTubePlayerFragment instances.

Comment: That may run into performance issues quickly as it is expensive to have every cell be a Fragment.